# Java ACM package

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, acm-java-libraries

I'm trying to write a java application in Eclipse.

I'm really wanting to use the ACM.Program package, however, my copy of Eclipse doesn't have it installed!

I've looked all over the net, and I can't find a single download for the ACM package.

More info:
Whenever I try the code:

```
package helloGeiodo;
import acm.program.*;

public class Add2 extends Program {

   public void run() {
      println("This program adds two numbers.");
      int n1 = readInt("Enter n1: ");
      int n2 = readInt("Enter n2: ");
      int total = n1 + n2;
      println("The total is " + total + ".");
   }

}
```

I get errors up and down the ying-yang, all implying that there is no such thing as "acm.program".

Anyways, I need to know where to find the ACM package, and, how to install it.

Thanks!

--Flynn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download `acm.jar` from the [ACM Java Task Force](http://jtf.acm.org/) and then [add it to your classpath](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

It appears that the previous link is dead. The files are still available at [Eric Roberts' Stanford page](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

The general answer is:

1. Download the JAR files from the relevant site
2. Copy (or import) them into your Eclipse project.  People often put external JARs into a `lib` directory, but that's just a personal choice.
3. Add them to the project's build path.

However, I wouldn't recommend using the "ACM" classes.  They were an interesting idea, but they didn't catch on.

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen - Teaching (and using) standard Java SE classes

Comment: I would agree on their usage but you could learn a lot by just browsing it's source code also as it is available at http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/ as the acm.zip

Comment: @DouglasG.Allen - Java SE library source code is also available.  Partial source code has *always* been available to programmers for free, and since Java 6 the entire codebase is available.  Frankly, if people want to read code, the Java SE code is more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the Stanford courses, you can import the Assignment directly (.zip files) into a new Java project.

Answer (score 0):

jtf.acm.org They let you download it there.